# Poisson Probabilities

Tags: probability

Suppose that on average five people move into a city per week. If this is a Poisson process:

a) Find the probability that the time until next arrival is more than three days. (Would this be the same as the probability of zero arrivals in the next three days?)

b) Find the expected time until the 250th arrival.

c) Use the normal distribution to estimate the probability that the 250th arrival happens after more than one year.

Not sure how to do those last two.

Thanks!

Comment: "Not sure how to do those last two." OK. But what did you try and/or think?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n$ be the time between the (n-1)-th and n-th jump, then $(S_n)_{n}$ are independent exponential r.v. with the parameter 5. Thus $E(\sum_{i=1}^{250} S_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{250} E(S_i) = \frac{250}{5} = 50$

Say there are 52.14 weeks in one year, then we want to compute $P(\sum_{i=1}^{250} S_i > 52.14)$ and $\sqrt{\frac{250}{\frac{1}{25}}}(\frac{1}{250}\sum_{i=1}^{250} S_i - \frac{1}{5})$ is approximatively the standard normal distribution by central limit theorem